# Projectile motion up a plane.

Tags: calculus, projectile-motion

I'm stuck on the following simple projectile motion problem up a plane.  Below is the question:

A plane is inclined at an angle $\alpha$ to the horizontal.  A particle is projected up the plane with speed $u$ at an angle $\beta$ to the plane.  The plane of projection is vertical and contains the line of greatest slope.  When the particle is at its maximum perpendicular height above the plane, it is $\frac{3}{5}$ of the range up the plane.  Show that **$\tan\alpha \tan\beta = \frac{2}{7}$**.

Here is what I did.

I set up a coordinate system parallel and perpendicular to the plane -  $\vec x$ (up the plane) and $\vec y$ (perpendicular to the plane).  Thus, I can express the initial velocity $u$ in terms if this coordinate system.

$$\vec u = u \cos\beta\vec x + u\sin\beta\vec y$$

Therefore

$$\vec u_x = u \cos\beta $$
$$\vec u_y = u \sin\beta $$

The acceleration due to gravity, in terms of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ is given by:

$$ \vec a = -g\sin\alpha \vec x - g\cos\alpha \vec y$$

Therefore

$$\vec a_x = -g\sin\alpha $$
$$\vec a_y = -g\cos\alpha $$

For maximum perpendicular height ($h$) I used $$(\vec v_y)^2 = (\vec u_y)^2 + 2\vec a_y h$$  Since $\vec v_y = 0 $ for maximum height, I can find $h$.

$$ 0 = u^2\sin^2\beta + 2(-g\cos\alpha)h$$
$$ h = \frac{u^2\sin^2\beta}{2g\cos\alpha}$$

To find the range, I first found the time of flight.  For the time of flight $\vec s_y = 0$.  Using the formula:

$$ \vec s_y = \vec u_yt + \frac{1}{2} \vec a_y t^2$$
$$ 0 = u\sin \beta t + \frac{1}{2}(-g\cos \alpha) t^2 $$
$$ t(u\sin \beta - \frac{1}{2}g\cos \alpha t) = 0 $$

$$t = 0 , t = \frac{2u\sin \beta}{g\cos \alpha}$$

Time of flight

$$ t = \frac{2u\sin \beta}{g\cos \alpha} $$

To find the range I used the formula

$$ \vec s_x = \vec u_xt + \frac{1}{2} \vec a_x t^2$$
$$ \vec s_x = u \cos\beta \biggl(\frac{2u\sin \beta}{g\cos \alpha}\biggl) + \frac{1}{2} (-g\sin \alpha)\biggl(\frac{2u\sin \beta}{g\cos \alpha}\biggl)^2$$
$$ \vec s_x  = \frac{2u^2\sin \beta \cos \beta}{g\cos \alpha} - \frac{2u^2 \sin \alpha \sin^2\beta}{g\cos^2 \alpha} $$

And this is where I get stuck.  I can seem to derive  **$\tan\alpha \tan\beta = \frac{2}{7}$**.

Comment: Formatting tip:  Your posts will be easier to read if you use `\cos`, `\tan`, `\log`, etc.

Comment: Thanks.... I just edited it with your recommendations.

Comment: "The plane of projection is vertical and contains the maximum slope."  I don't know what either part of that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Find the time to maximum perpendicular height. Then find the $x$ value at that time.  Set it equal to $3/5$ of the range expression you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is that the time taken to reach the maximum height is t/2, where t is the time of flight.

If you still cannot solve it, I have briefly written down the solution below.

$$s_{max\_ht} = \frac{u_xt}{2} + \frac{1}{2}.\frac{a_xt^2}{4} = \frac{3}{5}(u_xt + \frac{1}{2}a_xt^2)$$

$$\implies \frac{u_xt}{10} = \frac{a_xt^2}{2}.\frac{-7}{20}$$

Since you have taken $a_x$ as -g$\sin (\alpha)$, the negative sign gets cancelled and,

$$\frac{2u_x}{|a_x|t} = \frac{7}{2}$$

substituting the values of $u_x$, t, $|a_x|$ and taking the reciprocal, we get

$$tan(\alpha)tan(\beta) = \frac{2}{7}$$

Comment: Thanks cybershiptrooper, with this hint I think I can now solve my problem.